# How to access file from SDK in android?

Tags: android, sdk, typeface, custom-font

I'm developing a SDK for android and I need to load a `.ttf` font file into Typeface for use of custom font in the hosting app for the SDK I'm developing.

The current location for the `.ttf` file is the assets folder in the SDK and I can't access it.

If I put it in the hosting app assets folder it works fine but I don't want the user to add it manually in their assets folder, I want it to be transparent to the user.
I've tried using the `ClassLoader` or `getClass.getResources` and load it to URL (And the URL is not null) but I'm keep getting "native typeface cannot be made" RunTime exception.

Thanks for any assistance !